# How do I target the folder I want to deploy my web JS app in with Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, web, deployment, directory, azure-pipelines

I am really new to Azure DevOps especially when it comes to YAML pipelines.

I am developing a website split between backend and frontend.
The backend part is already developed and deployed on my linux server.

Now I want to deploy the frontend part (Vue JS) using YAML pipelines. The thing is I dont want the frontend part to be deployed in the same folder of the backend.

I know that the pipeline script "npm run build" creates a "dist" folder, so how can I force my azure pipelines to deploy the "dist" folder into a specific folder (let's say this specific folder is a subdirectory of "wwwroot" so it would be something like "wwwroot/subfolder/dist")

[image]

Thank you for all your help !

Comment: Hi Idash; could I ask you to clarify? Your yaml includes an [Azure Web App task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app), which is for deploying to an [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/app-service/), but in the question you say that the back end is already deployed *on your linux server*? Seems like a contradiction.

Comment: PS your question would be *much* better if you pasted your code in as text, rather than including a screenshot. It helps with indexability, searchability, etc.

Comment: hI @VinceBowdren thank you for helping me. I am not really familiar with stackoverflow, I apologize for not pasting the code directly. It looked less clear if pasted instead of a picture. Anyway, the YAML I just dropped above is for frontend deployment which has its own repo. Backend and frontend are separate into their respective repos but they are deployed on the same server. So I want the server to be well organized by deploying the front and the back in different directories.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, you need to deploy the dist folder to the specific folder in Web App.

I'm afraid you cannot implement it in Azure Web App task.

I suggest that you can try to use Azure CLI([az webapp deploy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp?view=azure-cli-latest#az_webapp_deploy)) to deploy the dist folder.

Here is an example:

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Azure CLI '
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    scriptType: ps
    scriptLocation: inlineScript
    inlineScript: 'az webapp deploy --resource-group ''some-resource-group'' --name ''some-webapp'' --src-path ''$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/SomeZip.zip'' --type zip --clean false --target-path some-subfolder'
```

Comment: Hi ! thank you for your help, I will try that way but could you explain me what "scriptType", "scriptLocation" and "inlineScript" fields mean ? What should I put into these fields ? 

Also, using "AzureWebApp@1" task, isnt it possible just to put something like : location : $(System.DefautWorkingDirectory)/specificFolder/dist ?

Comment: Oh a super important question I have please : do I have to create a service connection for each deployment ? Lets say my backend has its own repo with its pipelines and my frontend has its own repo with its pipelines. Can I use the same azure subscription in the pipeline YAML file in "AzureWebApp@1" task ?

Comment: Yes. You can use the same azure subscription. For the task definition, you can refer to this doc about [Azure CLI task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-cli?view=azure-devops).